# Trying to understand bash function return values

Tags: bash, function, return

I have looked at the bash function return values and it seems I still don't understand how that works.
I setup 3 function each supposedly returning a RET_VAL return value.
I assume func_1 returns either a 1 or 0 based on the if statement
I assume func_2 return either a 1 or a 0 based on the if statement
I assume func_3 should either print a 1 or a 0 based on the return value of func_2

```
func_1() {
  RET_VAL=0
  if [ -d /tmp/dir ]; then
    echo "Dir exists" 
    RET_VAL=0
  else
    echo "Dir doesn't exist"
    RET_VAL=1
  fi
  return ${RET_VAL}
}

func_2() {
  RET_VAL=0
  if func_1; then
    if [ -f /tmp/file_1]; then
      echo "File exists"
    else
      echo "File doesn't exist"
      RET_VAL=1
    fi
  else
    RET_VAL=1
  fi
  return ${RET_VAL}
}

func_3() {
  if func_2; then
    echo "Dir and File do exist"
  else
    echo "Dir and file do not exist"
  fi
}
```

Are my assumptions correct or is each function returning what it executed last, like the echo statement?
If so, how could I assure that the functions return a 1 or a 0 value?

Cheers,
Roland

Comment: **Beware** that shell variables are not function scoped by default, so the assignment of `RET_VAL` at the top of `func_2` will be immediately overwritten by the ones inside `func_1`. (In this case this happens to have no _net_ effect, in the behavior of the code, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func_3` will not print the return value of `func_2`. The `if` statement will *use* the exit status of `func_2` to determine which branch to take. *Every* command has an exit status, so in the absence of an explicit `return` command, the exit status of the last command to execute will be the exit status of a function. In the case of `func_3`, the exit status will be the exit status of whichever `echo` command executes (which is virtually always 0, absent any I/O errors).

Comment: Thank you @chepner for your fast response. So, if I understand correctly, if I would replace RET_VAL in each statement with an actual return 0, or return 1, this will return the actual 0 or 1 value and not the echo statement? Thank you

Comment: There's a difference between the exit status ("return value") of a function and its output. `echo` produces output; `return` sets the exit status of the function and immediately returns to the caller. Your assumptions about `func_1` and `func_2` appear to be correct.

Comment: Yes I do understand that echo and return have different behavior, function returns. Yet what confuses me is the last function statement is always a "return/exit" status set to either 0 or 1, and so why would the calling function not get the expected return value, or exit status, of 0 or 1?

Comment: I think I know what you mean by return value and exit status.

```
func(_1) {
  return 10
}

func_1
echo $?  # should be 0   
VALUE=$(func_1)
echo $VALUE # should be 10
```

Comment: No, return value and exit status are the same thing (though calling it an exit status helps emphasize the fact that you can't return arbitrary data from a function). `func_1 () { echo "foo"; return 10; }; VALUE=$(func_1); echo $?; echo $VALUE;` outputs 10 on the first line, `foo` on the second.

Comment: ok, thank you for your patients. So, "echo $?" statement carries the "exit" status which can be tested as "if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then" and an "echo" statement carries the "exit/return" value which can be listed as with "VALUE=$(func_1) ; echo $VALUE" and which could also possibly used in an if statement.

Comment: so, just to make sure, when using a return variable, RET_VAL, I can set that variable in the function and have it returned at the end of the function with either "echo ${RET_VAL}" or "return ${RET_VAL}" and I either have to test the value with either "$?" or "VAL=$(func_1); if [ "${VAL}" -eq "0" ]; then

Comment: `echo` *just* writes to standard output. Stop thinking of what it does as the return value of a function; you can have as many `echo` statements as you like in a function, and none of them cause the function to exit immediately. `echo` and `return` are *not* interchangeable. `return` can *only* return an integer value between 0 and 255.

Comment: `$(...)` *captures* the standard output of a command; it has nothing to do with capturing the exit status. The exit status of the most recent command is always found in `$?`.